# How do I read the whole number and fraction separately from input c++

Tags: c++, floating-point

My doubt is to skip a "`.`" from the input stream and read the whole number and the fractional parts in two different variables. Say I have an input like 10.26, I want store `10` in one variable `a` and `26` in another variable `b`.

In `C`, using `scanf` , I will do it like

`scanf("%d.%d",&a,&b);`

What is the equivalent way to do in `C++` using `cin`? or should I include `cstdio` and use the `scanf` itself?

Comment: scanf is perfectly possible in C++, besides using scanf_s instead

Comment: If this is for any kind of money calculations, use decimal, not float.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read the float as normal and use C-library's `modf` function to split the number:

```
#include <cmath>

float f = 0.0;
float ipart = 0.0;
float fpart = 0.0;

if (cin >> f)
    fpart = modf(f, &ipart);
else {
    // input failed
}
```

Let `operator>>` do the error checking!

Answer (score 2):

You can still use `scanf` in C++. If you want to use `cin`, then you can use [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to skip over the `.` in the input. Read the integers into variables as usual:

```
cin >> a;
cin.ignore(1, '.');
cin >> b;
```

Beware that whatever you use, you lose information about the fractional part. Whether the value is `.1` or `.001`, you'll find `b == 1` when you're finished. They're very different values, though.

Comment: You're not checking the return value of any of your input operations, which I'd consider a plain error.

Comment: Feel free to improve my answer if you think it's not good enough, @Kerrek.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
int egral;
unsigned int frac;
char sep;

if (!(std::cin >> egral >> sep >> frac) || sep != '.')
{
    // error, could not parse number
}

// integral part is 'egral, fractional part in 'frac'
```

Note that this would (wrongly?) parse `1.5E2` as `1 + 0.5`, and not as `150 + 0`. You'd have to add extra logic to handle scientific notation situations. It might be simpler to read an actual float and use `modf`.

Comment: It is not working. Try to use `123             .      \n\n\t   56` for an input.

Comment: @jirigracik: apart form a typo (fixed), it [works for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U2nIFRIZuCp59Vyj).

Comment: Who said it shouldn't work? Anyway, you can set `std::skipws` if you prefer. Or use `getline` and a string stream for more sophisticated line-based parsing.

Comment: Because we represent numbers as a sequence of digits. Optionaly we can add `.` or `,` followed by another sequence of digits. No whitespace in there.

Comment: @jirigracik: And my code supports that use case. What part of the question says that the code must reject whitespace?